# Android- How to end multiple AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app, i have an asynchronous task that will download a file from a remote server.
In that class, I have set a ProgressDialog that has a cancel button. It could have been easier if I just use that async task once and by creating and instance of the AsyncTask.
I could have just call `asyncTask.cancel(true)`, as what I saw on some samples.

But in my Activity, i have executed that AsyncTask many times like this:

```
new MyAsynTask().execute(url_of_file_1); 
new MyAsynTask().execute(url_of_file_2);
new MyAsynTask().execute(url_of_file_3);
```

Though this isn't exactly the structure but the sense is something like this.

This is how the `MyAsyncTask` looks like:

```
        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            ProgressDialog pdialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                if(!MyActivity.this.isFinishing()){
                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
                    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
                 }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... fileUrl) {

                try {

                    //do connection to url things
                    if(!isCancelled()){
                        // download the file

                    }else{
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }catch(MalformedURLException e){

                }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                }catch(Exception e){

                }
                return null;

            }


            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

                if(!MyActivity.this.isFinishing()){
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading..." + values[0]);
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if(!MyActivity.this.isFinishing()){
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }

            private final class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    new MyAsyncTask().cancel(true); // is this correct?
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
                    try {
                        MyActivity.this.finalize();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        application.shortToast("Error encountered in closing the page");
                    }
                    // maybe i should call super.onBackPressed();
                    application.shortToast("Download Cancelled");
                }
            }
        }
```

What happened when i press cancel is that it always have this exception, but my app won't crash sometimes though...

```
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623): Activity com.android.app.MyActivityhas leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f7c938 that was originally added here
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.app.MyActivityhas leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f7c938 that was originally added here
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:384)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at com.android.app.MyActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPreExecute(PartsActivity.java:784)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at com.android.app.MyActivity$SecondAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PartsActivity.java:980)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at com.android.app.MyActivity$SecondAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PartsActivity.java:1)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    08-14 23:07:12.702: E/WindowManager(8623):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
```

. . . .

So what is the proper way of ending those excuted AysnTask when i press the cancel button in my ProgressDialog?

Comment: Note that depending on the system you're running on, the AsyncTasks may be running sequentially!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep references of each task:
`MyAsynTask task1 = new MyAsynTask();`
`task1.execute(url_of_file_1);`

Since your exception is of other nature, you need to dismiss the dialog when you click the cancel button which is the event thread, not in the background thread.
In your Cancel button callback:
`myDialog.dissmiss()`
`task1.cancel(true);`

Comment: oh okay, i'll give it a shot